# Add HMRoom to HMHome is not working properly

Tags: ios, homekit

I have question regarding the HMRoom adding. When I am adding the HMRoom to HMHome it is added but after successful adding I am trying to load the HMHome rooms in a tableview. But it is not returning the rooms immediately. `- (void)home:(HMHome *)home didAddRoom:(HMRoom *)room` 
 method also not getting called even though I set the delegate for HMHome but calling homeManagerDidUpdateHomes method after 30 seconds. Could any one suggest me to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling the wrong method to add  Room to Home.
To add room to home you need to call,

```
- (void)addRoomWithName:(NSString *)roomName completionHandler:(void (^)(HMRoom *room, NSError *error))completion;
```

You can reload you table to get information of room you have added in **completionHandler** of **addRoomWithName** method. Which is called by object of HMHome in which you want to add a room.

The method you are calling,

```
- (void)home:(HMHome *)home didAddRoom:(HMRoom *)room toZone:(HMZone *)zone
```

is delegate method that is called when you add room to zone.

and make sure that you have set delegate of home properly.

Comment: In my question I have included that room is added I am using the same one which you have mentioned in your answer

Comment: By looking at your question, it seems you are not using the method. And you are looking for  (void)home:(HMHome *)home didAddRoom:(HMRoom *)room toZone:(HMZone *)zone  delegate  method.  Which is called when room is assigned to zone.  Batter you ask question properly.

Comment: My question says it is added to the room but why I need to use your addRoomWithName method ???. And one more thing is homeManagerDidUpdateHomes is not calling immediately....

Comment: I agree with your didAddRoom delegate method but thing is homeManagerDidUpdateHomes is not calling immediately. Could you help me resolve this issue.???

Comment: Yes, You just want to reload tableview when room is added. so why you are worring about homeManagerDidUpdateHomes delegate method? You can reload the table view or send notification from completionHandler. If you have specific reason to reload tableview from delegate method please specify.

Comment: Incase if I am immediately reloading the tableview then it is not reflecting the new room in tableview. I think it is taking time to add but if I go back and come to the view ( in which I am adding ) is showing that new room.

Comment: Check you array have updated values of rooms. That array should be updated.

Comment: Hmmm I  will check it